# Random letters and touch input on iPad

Tags: ipad, keyboard

A couple of days ago, my iPad started inserting random letters into what I was typing. For instance, I would try to type a C and a V would be typed. This would be the same for many letters. When I pressed Backspace to delete it would either delete multiple letters or insert various random letters. I reset the iPad and it worked better for a couple of days, but now symptoms have arisen again.  This has been happening when using Facebook, Messenger and Mail so it's not restricted to one app. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a couple variations of this problem before, and its usually one of 3 problems:

1. your touch screen is starting to malfunction. This is uncommon, but things happen with electronics. Seek repair from Apple.
2. Poorly conditioned electricity. Does this only happen when your iPad is plugged in? I had a generic plug that induced symptoms like you describe. Unplug the ipad and see if it still happens.
3. Liquid damage. This is probably the most frequent cause of electrical anomalies like this. Did anyone spill anything on the ipad, even if not recently?

Comment: Funnily enough it has been fine for a couple of days.  I did have a habit of using it whilst still plugged in to charge.  I thought that it was a malfunctioning touch screen but as it is fine again this seems unlikely.  thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your iPad is in a case or holder, remove it.

Switch off, and on again.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why your answer will solve the problem or is better than others out there.  Providing links can also help the OP, and others, find the software and evaluate it themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review